# How can I find my resource image

Tags: java

I am trying to load an image into a JLabel using:

```
java.net.URL imgURL =Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("MyLogo.png");
```

However, I always get a null pointer. I have tried every combination of my folder structure I could think of.

This is where file is on my c: drive, but I want to run as webapp.

```
C:\Users\JoJo\Eclipse\workspace1\proj1\src\main\resources\Images\MyLogo.png
```

I have tried things like:

`src/main/resources/Images/MyLogo.pn`g

Comment: Have you tried `/Images/MyLogo.png`?

Answer (score 0):

```
java.net.URL imgURL =Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/main/resources/Images/MyLogo.png");
```

That should do it.

As far as I know, The first `/` in the path indicates it should search inside the `.jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the directory to the class path

my advice is to add another folder in proj1 called resources and copy the image into it like so:

```
C:\Users\JoJo\Eclipse\workspace1\proj1\resources\Images\MyLogo.png
```

then you go in the project settings and set the classpath to include the `C:\Users\JoJo\Eclipse\workspace1\proj1\resources\` folder, then you can use `/Images/MyLogo.png`

Comment: In Eclipse I right-click the project > properties. Then under "Java Build Path" > Source I see proj1/src/main/resources. I put a copy of MyLogo.png in there - but I still get same error